# A specific part of the graph need integrated, it is from a polynomial but everytime a error shows up in rstudio

Tags: r, function, polynomials, integrate

I have these code:

```
f <- function(x){y ~ poly(x, 4)}

integrate(f, lower = 670, upper = 750)
```

also tried the code below:

```
f <- function(x){y ~ poly(x, 4)}

integrate(Vectorize(f, lower = 670, upper = 750))
```

I also tried this code but at both codes i get this error:

> Error in integrate(f, lower = 670, upper = 750) :
> evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `poly` does not give a generic polynomial with 5 coefficients, see its help page. You must have a function that can return a result to pass to `integrate`. This is not what `poly` is about, try, for instance, to run `poly(x, 4)(1)`. Also, in the function body, remove the `y ~`part, that's meant for formulas.

Comment: then it gives the error: Error in f(x, ...) : attempt to apply non-function

Comment: The point is that you have to define an integrand function and you haven't. `poly` does not return a function.